# When do we say class is loaded in java?

Tags: java

What does it mean when we say a `class` is "loaded"?

For example it is said that `Static init` blocks are executed at the time of class loading. When exactly `class` is loaded?

Please see this code from Kathy Sierra's book:

```
class Bird {
    {
        System.out.print("b1 ");
    }
    public Bird() {
        System.out.print("b2 ");
    }
}

class Raptor extends Bird {
    static {
        System.out.print("r1 ");
    }
    public Raptor() {
        System.out.print("r2 ");
    }
    {
        System.out.print("r3 ");
    }
    static {
        System.out.print("r4 ");
    }
}

class Hawk extends Raptor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("pre "); //1
        new Hawk();//2
        System.out.println("hawk ");
    }
}
```

**The output of above code is:** r1 r4 pre b1 b2 r3 r2 hawk

**I cant not understand howcome pre is printed after r1.** Which part of the code loaded Raptor class?

One of the answer says :

"the class is initialized at the last possible moment, but before any of its members is accessed".

But by that logic, shouldn't pre be printed BEFORE r1? Since line 2 accesses constructor of class Raptor AFTER execution of line1.

Comment: Doesn't this come down to your definition of "loaded"?

Comment: A class is loaded when you can have a reference to that class. Initialisation is a later step which is often done together, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Does that happen before the beginning of execution of main() method?

Comment: @SKG depends on your main class - if it references the class in one of its static fields, then certainly yes.

Comment: The class is always loaded if you call a main, but it might not be initialised in Java 8 depending on usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't confuse class *loading*, which is implementation-specific, and class *initialization*, which is very strictly specified. Unfortunately these two terms are often used as if they meant the same thing, but usually the phrase "the time of class loading" refers to the time of class *initialization*.

As an executive summary of the detailed case-by-case rules, the class is initialized at the last possible moment, but before any of its members is accessed.

With that part cleared up, in the code of your example you have a class `Hawk extends Raptor extends Bird`. `Hawk` is the class containing the entry point of your program, the method `main`. This is the init order:

1. Start initializing `Hawk`. Is its parent class `Raptor` initialized? no.
2. Start initializing `Raptor`. Is its parent `Bird` initialized? no.
3. Start initializing `Bird`.
4. Complete initializing `Bird`.
5. Execute `Raptor`'s static init blocks. This prints `r1 r4`.
6. Complete initializing `Raptor`.
7. Complete initializing `Hawk`.
8. Start executing `Hawk.main()`. This prints `pre`.

Comment: Hello Marko, I have edited the question. Can you please have a look again?

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. I completely missed constructor chaining. However I think your 5th point would be more complete with edit: Execute Raptor's "static" init blocks.

Comment: This isn't constructor chaining at all, no costructors run here. But you may say the same general pattern is followed.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought about it before, but it's basically a depth first search to find the base class (Bird here). It resolves all static initializers first, then calls "pre," creates a new Hawk instance which does another depth first search, except that the static initializers have already run, so it jumps to instance initializers and constructors, and then prints "hawk."

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you first attempt to use the class, e.g. try to create an instance, use one of its static methods or store reference to the class' `Class<?>` object.

Note that this may depend on the classloader implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Different JVMs load classes in different ways, but the basic rule is only loading classes when they are needed. If there are some other classes that are required by the loaded class, they will also be loaded. The loading process is recursive.

Below code is simple example of class and static block,variable laoding.

```
public class Foo {

    //instance variable initializer
    String s = "abc";

    //constructor
    public Foo() {
        System.out.println("constructor called");
    }

    //static initializer
    static {
        System.out.println("static initializer called");
    }

    //instance initializer
    {
        System.out.println("instance initializer called");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo();
        new Foo();
    }
}
```

Output for above program :

```
static initializer called
instance initializer called
constructor called
instance initializer called
constructor called
```

Comment: If you main() method is completely empty. It is still printing "static initializer called". At what point exactly Foo class is getting loaded?

Comment: main() method is present in Foo class. When we try to run the program it will start by finding starting point i.e. main() method in our project.In this scenario main() method is present in Foo class. So Classloader will load Foo class in memory for running main method. So while loading Foo class in memory other parameters like static block and variables will also gets loaded